# cascading proxy_pass in NGINX

Tags: nginx

I'd like to do something like the following:

```
location ~ ^/(?<upstream>[^/]+)/ {
  rewrite /$upstream/(.*) /api/public/$1  break;

  if ($upstream = "auth") {
    proxy_pass ${AUTH_SERVICE};
  }
  if ($upstream = "todos") {
    proxy_pass ${TODO_SERVICE};
  }
  if ($upstream = "analysis") {
    proxy_pass ${ANALYSIS_SERVICE};
  }
  if ($upstream = "stuff") {
    proxy_pass ${STUFF_SERVICE};
  }
  if ($upstream = "users") {
    proxy_pass ${USERS_SERVICE};
  }
  return 404;
}
```

The `proxy_pass` values are built fine with `envsubst`.

As an example, requests to `public-api.com/auth/*` would be mapped to `auth-service.com/api/public/*`.

When I make the request `curl http://localhost:8000/auth/ping`, I get a 404, but I can hit `auth-service.com/api/public/deep_ping` directly.

Can anyone spot the bug in the implementation? Is something like this even advisable?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the problem are the `if` statements. If an `if` matches, the rewrite rule will not be applied.

At least that is my understand after reading the [If Is Evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) article.

One alternative to deal with non-trivial logic is to use embedded scripting in Nginx. For instance, [embedded perl](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_perl_module.html) or Lua (part of for [OpenResty](https://openresty.org/en/)). There is some overhead in setting it up, but as you are then using a normal programming language, implementing complex logic is easier as there are less surprises.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the link Philipp. From reading it, I was able to understand how this works (and is safe):

```
location ~ /(?<api>[^/]+)/ {
  set $backend 0;

  if ($api = "auth") {
    set $backend ${AUTH_SERVICE};
  }
  if ($api = "todos") {
    set $backend ${TODO_SERVICE};
  }
  if ($api = "analysis") {
    set $backend ${ANALYSIS_SERVICE};
  }
  if ($api = "stuff") {
    set $backend ${STUFF_SERVICE};
  }
  if ($api = "users") {
    set $backend ${USERS_SERVICE};
  }

  if ($backend = 0) {
    return 404;
  }

  rewrite /([^/]+)/(.*) /$2 break;
  proxy_pass $backend;
}
```